# How to stop Rails route preempting another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an API for a mobile app. I am running into a problem where one of my routes is preempting another. The two routes are:

```
api_vocabs_all GET    /api/vocabs/all(.:format)      api/vocabs#all
api_vocab GET    /api/vocabs/:id(.:format)      api/vocabs#show
```

Whenever I navigate to "api/vocabs/all" Rails sends the request to the show method with the id = all. Is there a way around this?

Update: Looking at my code again I noticed that while the above doesn't work the non-api version does work. Do I need to put my route inside the namespace?

```
vocabs_all GET    /vocabs/all(.:format)          vocabs#all
vocab GET    /vocabs/:id(.:format)          vocabs#show
```

Below are all my routes from routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
 resources :vocabs
end
get 'vocabs/all' => 'vocabs#all'
get 'api/vocabs/all' => 'api/vocabs#all'
resources :vocabs
```

Comment: Is the api_vocabs_all route defined above api_vocab?

Comment: I have added my routes to the bottom of my post. Api_vocabs_all is defined outside of the namespace while the resources :vocabs appears above it (which contains api_vocab)

Comment: RESTful way configuring routes to get list of resources is `get 'vocabs' => 'vocabs#all'`. See the discarded `/all` path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer. Put `api/vocabs/all` above the `namespace :api`. Remember that your routing file should be ordered from *most specific* to *least specific*.

```
get 'api/vocabs/all' => 'api/vocabs#all'
namespace :api do
 resources :vocabs
end
get 'vocabs/all' => 'vocabs#all'
resources :vocabs
```

Comment: That did it sir! Thank you